# eclipse opencv android ndk: The project was not built due to "'NUL' is an invalid name on this platform."

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to build and run the 'Tutorial 2 Advanced - 1. Add Native OpenCV' tutorial built into the opencv package for android. I wasn't able to use the ndk-build from eclipse following the tutorial from http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

But, I built the project from cygwin successfully. But then when trying to run as an android application in Eclipse, it has the error

'Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built due to "'NUL' is an invalid name on this platform.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent   Tutorial 2 Advanced - 1. Add Native OpenCV      Unknown Java Problem'

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What exactly did you build with Cygwin? I've had an error which prevented me from building from the command prompt but with Cygwin everything works fine.

In Cygwin I first navigate to my project folder:
**cd /cygdrive/c/"path to your project folder>"/**

then while I'm in the project folder type:
**/cygdrive/c/"path to android-ndk-r7b folder"/ndk-build**

After using these commands I was able to run the Tutorial 2 Advanced - 1. Add Native OpenCV project. Let me know if this helps you?